# Safe navigation operator in JSONPath?

Tags: jsonpath

Ruby and many languages support [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator):

```
name = article&.author&.name
```

Is there any equivalent in JSONPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unnecessary in JSON Path.  Navigation is safe by default.  If a value doesn't exist at a given path, the node set returned will just be empty; it shouldn't error.

This may, of course, vary between implementations as we don't have a standard yet, but we're [working on one](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base).